# Scanner is not working on StringBuilder

Tags: java

I wrote a program that must take input from a file and extract only text from it while saving its contents into an array. My text file contents are:

```
There is some!text.written%in
the FILE[That]=Have+to`be==separated????
```

And what I have tried to code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mfile.txt"));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList();
    String str;
    StringBuilder filedata = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner toknizer = new Scanner(filedata.toString());
    while((str=file.readLine())!=null){
        filedata.append(str);
    }
    toknizer.useDelimiter("[^a-z]");
    while(toknizer.hasNext()){
        list.add(toknizer.next());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

at this time I only want to extract text that is written in small alphabets. But the program is printing out an empty list. Debugging revealed that `toknizer.hasNext()` is returning false in `while(toknizer.hasNext())`.
What is wrong? Am I using wrong regular expression? I got the idea of using `[^a-z]` from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Scanner toknizer = new Scanner(filedata.toString());
```

You just created a `Scanner` around an empty string.
That's not going to have any tokens.

Strings are immutable; appending to the `StringBuilder` later does not affect the existing `String` instance you passed to the `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it like this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // If List is generic then ArrayList should be too
    Scanner input = null;

    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File("mfile.txt"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }

    input.useDelimiter("[^a-z]");
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String parse = input.next();
        if(!parse.equals("")) {
            list.add(parse);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

Now you don't have to use a `BufferedReader`, `FileReader` or a `StringBuilder`.